# How to hide tippy js tooltip after some seconds onclick?

Tags: tippyjs

Is there any default method to hide tooltip after a few seconds on click?
I want to show it on click for 2 sec and then close it. how should i do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to set a timeout when the tooltip is first shown. I also like to add `hideOnClick: false` so that it doesn't disappear when they click somewhere else.

Here's a complete example for you:

```
tippy('#button', {
  trigger: 'click',
  hideOnClick: false,
  onShow(instance) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      instance.hide();
    }, 2000);
  }
});
```